# Swift: get text of TextView inside TableView (two approaches possible)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a TableView with editable TextViews inside it and I would like to check whether they contain text or not when the user tries to move to the next page. However I'm not sure how to reference them from inside the TableView. Any ideas?

Here's the setup I have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ActionCell", for: indexPath) as! StepCell

    // Cell Formatting

    cell.label.delegate = self
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

Then an extension for the textview delegate:

```
extension Step3: UITextViewDelegate {


func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let cell = textView.superview?.superview as? StepCell
    let indexPath = tableview.indexPath(for: cell!)
    goals[goals.count - 1].steps![indexPath!.row].title = textView.text
    resizeTableViewCell()
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" || text == "\t" {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
    }
}
```

And in my viewcontroller a button that will advance to the next page if all fields have text.

Every step gets added with empty text to the Goal object whenever it gets created, so I considered checking in the array to see if the object has any text, but this is an array inside another array and I couldn't get that to work. I tried something like below, but I get an error saying Type 'Goal' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

```
@IBAction func nextTU(_ sender: Any) {

    for steps in goals[0] {
        print(steps.steps)
}
```

If it's of any importance, here's the code that adds a step:

```
@IBAction func addTU(_ sender: Any) {
    goals[goals.count - 1].steps?.append(Step(title: ""))
}
```

The struct for Goals looks like this:

```
struct Goal: Codable, Equatable {
    var title: String
    var description: String?
    var duration: String
    var steps: [Step]?
    var completedSteps: [Step]?
    var completed: Bool
    var dateCreated: Date

    func returnYear(date: Date) -> Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        return calendar.component(.year, from: date)
    }
}
```

And the one for Step is just this:

```
struct Step: Codable, Equatable {
    var title: String
}
```

So to recap, I would either need to check the text of all textViews inside the TableView, or to iterate through an array inside an array.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have many sections or it's 1

Comment: There's just one section in the tableview, but the user can add as many rows as they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`goals[0]` is an object of type `Goal`  you can't iterate over it , You need

```
@IBAction func nextTU(_ sender: Any) { 
   for step in goals.last!.steps {
       if step.text == "" {
          // alert user 
       }
   }
}
```

**OR**

```
goals.last?.steps!.forEach { 
    if $0.title == "" {
       print("I'm empty!") 
    } 
}
```

Above you should use `goals.last!.steps`   as here `goals[goals.count - 1]` you set all the values to the last item in the array

Comment: Thank you, but that returns an error saying that: Type '[Step]?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence' and just adding Sequence to Step isn't enough to get it to conform. Any idea why it's saying this or how to fix it?

Comment: I have added both Step and Goal to the original question.

Comment: Hey @Sh_Khan, I managed to get it working. It turns out if I use forEach instead of a for in loop, it will work. If you want to update your answer, I'll accept it.

goals.last?.steps!.forEach { step in
            if step.title == "" {
                print("I'm empty!")
            }
}